# Reuse one web response in .net and rest for many operations

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core

I have a question.

I have a simple service that do requests and streams back response to file and it looks like:

```
public async ValueTask GetWaetherByLocation(string place)
{
    try
    {
        const string locationEndpoint = "https://localhost/api/place/?query=";

        var fullEndpoint = $"{locationEndpoint}{place}";
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(fullEndpoint);
        WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

        ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition;

        var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(response.Headers["Content-Disposition"], out contentDisposition)
            ? contentDisposition.FileName
            : "place.dat";

        var filePath = Path.Combine(assemblyPathInfo, fileName);

        using var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        await response.GetResponseStream().CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex);
    }
}
```

My question is can I reuse stream to cast reponse to some model without the need to send request once more or opening file data is beeing streamed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [response caching middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-5.0)?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddResponseCaching();
    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

By query key would help you:

```
var responseCachingFeature = context.HttpContext.Features.Get<IResponseCachingFeature>();

if (responseCachingFeature != null)
{
    responseCachingFeature.VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "MyKey" };
}
```